# KICS Checkmarx with Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, infrastructure-as-code, checkmarx

I'm planning to use `KICS by Checkmarx` to scan the `Terraform` Infrastructure Code.
This is the example I got online `https://docs.kics.io/1.3.1/integrations_azurepipelines/#integrate_kics_with_azure_pipelines`

But, I'm facing some difficulties using this in the `Azure DevOps` Release Pipeline.

Please let me know if anyone used it for terraform using Azure Pipelines. It'd be a great help if I get some pointers.

**This is what I tried so far :**
[image]

**And Getting this Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a very outdated version of the documentation.

Here is the link to Azure DevOps Integration of the latest version:
https://docs.kics.io/latest/integrations_azurepipelines/

Comment: Please let me know which type of Activity is this within Azure DevOps Pipeline Tasks. Is it Commandline Task type?

Comment: Yes. Indeed it is.

Comment: Please check the Question again. I tried as mentioned and updated the error info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is the fact the code you copied from KICS docs is more than a simple script: it's a sample code of a Azure DevOps pipeline.
In Azure DevOps, there are two ways to create a pipelines:

- Classic UI
- YAML pipeline

You can check online the differences between both but in short, the "YAML pipeline" is the newer way to define a pipeline (just like you can write a YAML pipeline in GitLab, Github, Bitbucket,...).

In your first screenshot, you're using "Classic UI" to define your pipeline, but you can define it also in YAML (that's what the sample code provided by KICS documentation is).

```
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

container: checkmarx/kics:debian

steps:
  # running in CI mode, exporting results to a JSON file and printing the results in stdout
  # KICS should fail the pipeline if results are found
  - script: |
      /app/bin/kics scan --ci -p ${PWD} -o ${PWD}
      cat results.json
```

Just create a YAML pipeline in your repository, give it any name you want (ex: azure-pipelines-kics.yaml) and copy paste it.
From top to bottom, what does this pipeline do is:

- to be triggered whenever "master" branch is updated
- Agent "ubuntu-latest" has to be used
- container: this field tells the system to fetch a Docker image (in this case checkmarx/kics image with tag "debian") from Docker Hub and then start the container
- The rest of the steps are executed inside of the container (which is executing kics)